# static files have extension only allow for downloads

Tags: nginx, download

i am trying to setup nginx download allow only have extension
i have static files .txt .kvm and some files is without extension in `/var/www/download/`
i am trying to file with extension `(.txt .kvm etc *.*)` download allow via nginx and other all without extension files not allow direct download

how can i do this in nginx.conf

my nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen       8000;
    listen       somename:8080;
    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/download;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
location ~* (?<filename>[^/]+\.(mp3|jpg|jpeg|etc))$ {
    #add or remove all the extensions you need.
    add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="$filename"';
}
```

Also if you have other files without extension, just add another location that matches them and add this header, make sure to pass the filename.